# #include <openssl/evp.h> in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, encryption, include

I want to include `openssl/evp.h`. Xcode says "No such file or directory".

I managed to compile the whole OpenSSL C library and use it.

However, I want to use the cryptography library that's **natively available in iOS**.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

tools compiler settings > global & variable > add include folder